# Problem with \defbibentryset and repeated citations

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I am trying to sort my bibliography employing \defbibentryset. to generate a cite with the style i.e:

[3] a) First source b) Second source c)Third source.

The problem is, when I cite again one of the sources in a predefined set using \defbibentryset in other page, it gets repeated in the footnote in this page. This behaviour only happens in this case, if the source is not part of a set, it gets ommited in case it is repeated, as it should be.

This is bad because I only want the source to be cited when it is called for the first time.

Here I post a minimal working example with the code I am using. The code was taken from somewhere else as I am pretty new to Latex. Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subentry,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}


\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{10mm}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\defbibentryset{set1}{cotton,hammond}

Lets cite a set that includes Cotton and Hammond \superfullcite{set1}. And a cite Goossens that it is not part of a set \superfullcite{companion}.

\newpage

Now lets cite only Cotton \superfullcite{cotton}. As you can see this citation should be omited in the footnote as it is already present is page one (unwanted behaviour). And now lets cite Goossens. This cite is ommited in footnotes because it is repeated and it is not part of a set (right behaviour).\superfullcite{companion} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `biblatex` doesn't count a `@set` entry as cited for `\ifciteseen` if the whole set was cited, we need to define an additional test to cater for this case.

```
\newcommand*{\ifsetentryseen}{%
  \iffieldundef{entrysetcount}
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\ifentryseen{\thefield{entryset}}}}
```

Tests if the current citation is a set entry whose set parent was cited before. Then use the test together with `\ifciteseen`

```
\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifciteseen} or test {\ifsetentryseen}}
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subentry,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newcommand*{\ifsetentryseen}{%
  \iffieldundef{entrysetcount}
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\ifentryseen{\thefield{entryset}}}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifciteseen} or test {\ifsetentryseen}}
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\defbibentryset{set1}{cotton,hammond}

Lets cite a set that includes Cotton and Hammond \superfullcite{set1}. And a cite Goossens that it is not part of a set \superfullcite{companion}.

\newpage

Now lets cite only Cotton \superfullcite{cotton}. As you can see this citation should be omited in the footnote as it is already present is page one (unwanted behaviour). And now lets cite Goossens. This cite is ommited in footnotes because it is repeated and it is not part of a set (right behaviour).\superfullcite{companion} 
\end{document}
```

Without footnotes on page 2.

Comment: It works great, moewe. Thank you a lot!